# Replace null value of selected paper-item in paper-dropdown-menu with object

Tags: polymer, paper-elements

I can't manage to get this simple binding of `site.address.country` working:

My backend returns a json-object like this in case the country is not set:

```
{ "address" : { "street" : null, "country" : null } }
```

With this structure, when the `paper-dropdown-menu` is changed, Polymer does not seem to be able to replace the `null`-value of country with

```
{ "address" : { "street" : null, "country" : { "id" : "lu" } } }
```

What would be the proper way to have Polymer replace the null-value of country with `{ "id" : "lu" }`?

This is my code so far:

```
<paper-dropdown-menu label="Country">
    <paper-menu attr-for-selected="value" selected="{{site.address.country.id}}" class="dropdown-content">
        <paper-item value="lu">Luxembourg</paper-item>
    </paper-menu>
</paper-dropdown-menu>
<paper-input value="{{site.address.street}}" label="Street"></paper-input>
```

I could but don't want to do something hacky like replacing the value after I got it from the backend, à la:

```
siteLoaded: function(e) {
    if (!e.detail.response.address.country) {
        e.detail.response.address.country = { "id" : "" };
    }
    this.set("site", e.detail.response);
}
```

Comment: your object should look like `{ "address" : { "country" : {id:"lu"}, "street": "foo" } }`. Does that look exactly like this?

Comment: I have reformulated my question because the problem turned out to be a different one...

Comment: Your json doesn't look like json

Comment: Thanks for noticing @codeMonkey, I fixed it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following method for defining a default value for the property of type Object (by defining a function that returns the default Object):

```
...

Polymer({
    is : "site-form",
    properties : {
        site : {
            type : Object,
            value :  function() { return { "address" : { "country" : {id: 0} } }; }
        }
    },
...
```

**EDIT:**
After your reformatting the question, I understand the issue. In your case, *country.id is undefined*, so I suppose your hacky way should be the best solution for proper binding.

Comment: I have reformulated my question because the problem turned out to be a different one...

Comment: Now I understand your issue better. Updating my answer.